# How to send Scheduled-time notifications using SQL Server and Windows Azure Notification Hubs?

Tags: sql-server, architecture, notifications, job-scheduling, azure-notificationhub

Let me explain the current scenario of what we already do and then what we are trying to achieve.

**Existing Architecture:** In our current architecture, we have a bunch of services and a SQL Server DB. The services allows a Mobile device (Android/IOS) to allow the user to register/login and then set-up his schedule, say, "I need to have lunch at 12:00 noon".

The Android app, polls for all the schedules for the device for the next day, at the end of current day and then shows those schedules at their appropriate time the next day.

The **problems** with this approach is that, **first**, possibly (as reported to me) IOS can not do something like keeping the schedules in background and then showing when time occurs and **second**, this isn't the best way to handle this - What if user changes the schedule 'after' the Mobile app has done its scheduling.

---

So, I came up with an architecture for solving this problem (**Proposed Architecture 1**) and on further investigation also thought of a different way of handling this (**Proposed Architecture 2**) and mentioning that too here below. Can you help me in resolving my queries for the same and trying to understand what would work best:

**Proposed Arch. 1:** Please see the below diagram -
[image: Proposed Architecture 1 - Diagram]

This architecture is pretty straight forward. We propose here that we can use a **SQL Dependency + Query notification** to know the changes in Schedule table (Which contains all the schedules and when any user adds, updates, or deletes a schedule, a query notification will be thrown). This SQL Server is residing separately and is not on cloud.

Our **Azure Mobile Service** will have a **handler for this query notification** and as soon as it gets a notification, it'll update its own Azure SQL DB with updated schedules and then it'll 'prompt' its own scheduler to target it self for next re-invoke - that is - the **scheduler will check the schedules** in Azure SQL DB and will, if there are notifications to send, then send the notifications using Notification hub and then re-schedule itself for the **next time when it has to send the notification**

Now the biggest question with this approach is - *We are pretty sure that we might have hundreds or even thousands of users updating their schedule at the same time - and when that happens, I'm not user how this architecture will behave - will it break? - Also, if the scheduler runs and finds that it has to send, say, 1000 notifications for a particular time, say 6:00 pm, will it, if not break then will it introduce too much latency in the notifications - say a notification that was supposed to be sent at 6:00 pm is getting sent at around 6:05 pm*

---

While thinking of the problem, we came up with this next proposed architecture:

**Proposed Arch. 2:**

Under this architecture, we thought that why not just shift the scheduling thing to SQL server and create a job that runs every minute (because, no one is setting a schedule under a minute - that is - a person will set up a schedule at 6:35 pm not at 6:35:09 pm)

Also, this process only involves SQL CLR Objects and Notification Hubs and no Azure Mobile Service or Azure SQL DB.

So, the process will be something like this:

- A SQL Server Job will be scheduled to run every one minute
- Say if the job started at 5:00 pm it will look if there are any scheduled notifications for 5:01 pm - If yes, then start sending its notifications
- If not, then conclude silently and then re-invoke itself at 5:01 pm to see if there are any schedules for 5:02 pm
- Continue in the same fashion until explicitly stopped

*The primary concern is that will this work?*

*Is it a good practice to schedule a job for every minute (even though SQL Server has that option)?*

*What if, the job finds at 5:01 pm that it has 10,000 notifications to send at 5:02 pm? Will it be able to send all of those*

BTW, in this architecture to send the notifications we'll be using the Azure Notification Hub and there will be a SQL CLR function say, 'send notification' which will hook to this notification hub and will send the notification when called by the scheduled job.

**Please suggest me other links that will point to a better way of handing this. My client is very concerned about the way we'll be handling the notifications if we'd have to send too many at a time**

Thanks a lot for all those who answer/comment! :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you explore possibly using SendScheduledNotifications API of Notification Hubs. You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790626.aspx .

Comment: Yes, sending scheduled notification is something that I explored initially itself - but then - it'll be tricky to use because, the user might actually even cancel the schedule or completely change it in the last minutes and that might lead to even accidentally sending him notification when its not desired - BTW how would you suggest sending the notification to a user that, say, wants the notification to be at 12:10 PM.